# Автоматическое расставление переносов

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Суть вопроса, есть `textarea`, при вставке в нее текст отправляется на сервер, и записывается в бд, потом выводится на сайте. Возможно ли сделать так чтобы сохранялось форматирование текста, без использования редакторов вроде `CKEditor`?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php должно помочь. перед сохранением, замените переносы строки на `<br>`

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap` же. Только не похоже, что вопрос вообще об этом.